# how to fix horizontal collapsing problem?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5 to design my template, and I'm facing an issue: When I press the button "Menu" `
, not all of the sidebar fades(i'm trying  horizontal collapsing plugin and i want the sidebar collapse when i press menu button ), and I have this dark space, as shown in this picture [image]. How can I fix it? this is my  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
         <div class="collapse collapse-horizontal" id="collapseWidthExample">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span></a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span> </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">loser</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col py-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseWidthExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseWidthExample">
                Menu
            </button>
            <h3>Left Sidebar with Submenus</h3>
            <p class="lead">
                An example 2-level sidebar with collasible menu items. The menu functions like an "accordion" where only a single 
                menu is be open at a time. While the sidebar itself is not toggle-able, it does responsively shrink in width on smaller screens.</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
# 

I tried several solutions, but none of them worked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing these grid selectors from the parent container here:

`col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2`

which are displaying empty dark container on those breakpoints

and also add `show` to the collapsible container to make it show initially.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    
        <div class="col-auto px-0 bg-dark">
         <div class="collapse collapse-horizontal show" id="collapseWidthExample">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span></a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span> </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">loser</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col py-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseWidthExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseWidthExample">
                Menu
            </button>
            <h3>Left Sidebar with Submenus</h3>
            <p class="lead">
                An example 2-level sidebar with collasible menu items. The menu functions like an "accordion" where only a single 
                menu is be open at a time. While the sidebar itself is not toggle-able, it does responsively shrink in width on smaller screens.</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you wish to hide it on certain breakpoint, mobile for example, then maybe hardcode your own breakpoint on which you can hide the button and sidebar, because using Bootstrap's display utility will interfere with collapsible plugin.

For example, hide both sidebar and button on some arbitrary breakpoint on mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #collapseWidthExample,
  button[data-bs-target="#collapseWidthExample"] {
    display:none !important;
  }
}
```